# Angular 2/4 HostListener not clicking on right event?

Tags: angular

I have a directive `myPopUp`which I attached to `<a>` elements to get the link

However, when I add an image to the `<a>` tag, `@HostListener` only grabs the `img`, and doesn't bubble up.

How do I get the a tag reference when there is an image inside?

Here is my plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/80OGOKLSW3HjJfXjP7O2?p=preview (view console)

and the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <a href="http://google.com" myPopUp> 
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
    </a>
    <br/>
     <a href="http://google.com" myPopUp> 
     This works fine, event is A tag
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {

  @Directive({ selector: '[myPopUp]' })

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(event.target);
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're observing comes from the fact that `target` refers to the element you clicked on. In the first example, there's nothing inside the `<a>` tag so when you click on it it is the element that registers the click and you get the reference to the `<a>`. In the second example the click is actually registered on the `<img>` and that's why it's referenced in the `target`.

If you put `@HostListener` on the directive `myPopUp`, you could reach the `<a>` element using `currentTarget`:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myPopUp]' })
class myPopUp {
    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
    }
}
```

But if you want to have `@HostListener` on the root element your only solution is to use node traversal and reference `parentNode`:

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(event.target.parentNode);
  }
```

but that assumes that `<img>` is always the direct child of `<a>` element.

Comment: Thanks. That works for when an link has a image nested, but what's strange is that Angular doesn't seem to be bubbling @HostLIstener. It just logs a or img, it should theoretically keep logging up the DOM tree

Comment: what do you mean `keep logging up the DOM tree`?

Comment: @mrsq the hostListener callback is only fired once on click, but you can see the click event does bubble up the DOM tree https://plnkr.co/edit/tN3ojjy0Nh78k8kzQmX8?p=preview

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I noticed the same thing is a javascript example https://jsfiddle.net/6hc5nnxs/ I guess now the trick is how to get the a tag reference

Comment: I'll mark it, thanks for your inputs. At least I can your the parentNode to write some conditionals.